# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Set Select Element Width to match its containers width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select box that is too short for my liking. I want it to automatically resize to its containers width (in this case the blue box in col-md-6) below

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <select class="input-xlarge">
   <option>...</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this so it fits in the whole blue space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has a built-in class for this that works on `input` and `select`: `.form-control`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <select class="form-control input-lg">...</select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-8">
   <select class="form-control">...</select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-5">
   <select class="form-control input-sm">...</select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is answer is what you need :)

Answer (score -1):

IF you set the width for the select element to 100% it will cover the whole with of the col-md-6

```css
select {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
 <select class="input-xlarge">
   <option>...</option>
 </select>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer does not rely on Bootstrap as a solution, and you're including version 4 when the OP specifically notes they are using v3.

Comment: Your solution would work regardless of any CSS framework; but why provide an answer that ignores the framework being used when that framework already provides a solution?